# Does Room, DB and DAO need to be in the same package?

Tags: java, android, sql, mvvm, android-room

Im having a hard time creating a database for my login UI. Currently using a local DB with room just to start testing. I will set up a rest api and remote db later once done testing. While I have been able to get it to work on other tutorials, it appears the classes are all in the same package. With my current application I am building, I separated my packages into the types of classes they are / what they are used for I.E. Activities, Fragments, DAOs, ViewModels, Interfaces, Adapters etc. Everything works fine up until I try to initialize the db in my viewmodel. Using the debugger I can see that INSTANCE is null during the getDatabase function all the way up until the .build() and that is where it crashes.

Here is the exception log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.whatever, PID: 13042
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.whatever/com.example.whatever.activities.LoginActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.whatever.viewModels.ViewModelEmailLogin
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1534)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1424)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.whatever.viewModels.ViewModelEmailLogin
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:275)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at com.example.whatever.ui.fragments.EmailLoginFragment.onCreateView(EmailLoginFragment.java:74)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:310)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2617)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2569)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6959)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2890)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1534) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1424) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.example.whatever.ui.fragments.EmailLoginFragment.onCreateView(EmailLoginFragment.java:74) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:310) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2617) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2569) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6959) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2890) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1534) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1424) 
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.whatever.db.WhatEverUserDB. WhatEverUserDB_Impl does not exist
        at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:94)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:952)
        at com.example.whatever.db.WhatEverUserDB.getDatabase(WhatEverUserDB.java:45)
        at com.example.whatever.repositories.WhatEverUserRepo.<init>(WhatEverUserRepo.java:33)
        at com.example.whatever.viewModels.ViewModelEmailLogin.<init>(ViewModelEmailLogin.java:31)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.example.whatever.ui.fragments.EmailLoginFragment.onCreateView(EmailLoginFragment.java:74) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:310) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2617) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2569) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6959) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2890) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1534) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1424) 
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
```

Model

```
package com.example.whatever.db;

import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;



// This is an object used to create a WhatEver User
//debating if we should use WhatEver user to link to other social media accounts
// we could create lists of social sites with accounts that gather the info from the db


import java.util.List;
@Entity(tableName = "whatever_user_table")
public class WhatEverUser {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)// with each new row we add to the db, room will automatically create a new id
    private int ID;

    private CharSequence Username;

    private CharSequence Email;

    private CharSequence Password;





    public WhatEverUser(CharSequence Username, CharSequence Email, CharSequence Password){
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Password = Password;



    }

    public CharSequence getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public CharSequence getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public CharSequence getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setUsername(CharSequence username) {
        this.Username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(CharSequence password) {
        Password = password;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public void setEmail(CharSequence email) {
        this.Email = email;
    }
}
```

DB

```
package com.example.whatever.db;

import android.content.Context;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;

import com.example.whatever.interfaces.WhatEverUserDAO;

import com.example.whatever.db.WhatEverUser;


import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;




@Database(entities = {WhatEverUser.class},version = 1)
public abstract class WhatEverUserDB extends RoomDatabase {

    private static volatile WhatEverUserDB INSTANCE;     // this is an instance of our database

    public abstract WhatEverUserDAO whatEverUserDAO();     //we use this method to access our dao
    // we use this method to access our db methods in the dao

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;

    static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor =
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);



    public static WhatEverUserDB getDatabase(final Context context){
        if (INSTANCE == null){
            synchronized (WhatEverUserDB.class){
                if (INSTANCE == null){
                    INSTANCE =  Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            WhatEverUserDB.class,
                            "whatever_user_table")
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .addCallback(roomCallback)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }



    private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){

        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {

                WhatEverUserDAO whatEverUserDAO = INSTANCE.whatEverUserDAO();

                WhatEverUser admin = new WhatEverUser("admin","admin@admin.com","password");
                whatEverUserDAO.insertUser(admin);
                WhatEverUser test1 = new WhatEverUser("test1","test1@test1.com","test1234");
                whatEverUserDAO.insertUser(test1);

            });
        }
    };













}

    //creating the database
 /*   public static synchronized whatEverUserDB getInstance(final Context context){     //we create our only db instance, synchronized means only one thread can access this db at a time.
        if (instance == null){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), whatEverUserDB.class, "whatever_user_database")
                    //.enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()
                    //.allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() //if we don't do this and try to increase the version, the app will crash, this avoids this by deleting the tables and starting from scratch
                    //.addCallback(roomCallback)
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    */



 /*   private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
          //  new PopulateDBAsyncTask(instance).execute();
        }
    };


 private  static class PopulateDBAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { // Creating this async task to populate the db for test users
        private WhatEverUserDAO whatEverUserDAO;

        private PopulateDBAsyncTask(whatEverUserDB db){
            whatEverUserDAO = db.whatEverUserDAO();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            whatEverUserDAO.insertUser(new WhatEverUser("admin","admin@admin.com","password"));
            whatEverUserDAO.insertUser(new WhatEverUser("test1","admin1@admin.com","password"));
            whatEverUserDAO.insertUser(new WhatEverUser("test2","admin2@admin.com","password"));


            return null;
        }
    }

*/






// must extend roomDb and be abstract
// version must be changed every time we create a new db from scratch
// we should not leave userDB on devices, this will eventually need to be grabbed from our own sql server so this class may be removed later TODO
```

DAO

```
package com.example.whatever.db;

import android.content.Context;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;

import com.example.whatever.interfaces.WhatEverUserDAO;

import com.example.whatever.db.WhatEverUser;


import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;




@Database(entities = {WhatEverUser.class},version = 1)
public abstract class WhatEverUserDB extends RoomDatabase {

    private static volatile WhatEverUserDB INSTANCE;     // this is an instance of our database

    public abstract WhatEverUserDAO whatEverUserDAO();     //we use this method to access our dao
    // we use this method to access our db methods in the dao

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;

    static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor =
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);



    public static WhatEverUserDB getDatabase(final Context context){
        if (INSTANCE == null){
            synchronized (WhatEverUserDB.class){
                if (INSTANCE == null){
                    INSTANCE =  Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            WhatEverUserDB.class,
                            "whatever_user_table")
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .addCallback(roomCallback)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }



    private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){

        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {

                WhatEverUserDAO whatEverUserDAO = INSTANCE.whatEverUserDAO();

                WhatEverUser admin = new WhatEverUser("admin","admin@admin.com","password");
                whatEverUserDAO.insertUser(admin);
                WhatEverUser test1 = new WhatEverUser("test1","test1@test1.com","test1234");
                whatEverUserDAO.insertUser(test1);

            });
        }
    };













}

    //creating the database
 /*   public static synchronized whatEverUserDB getInstance(final Context context){     //we create our only db instance, synchronized means only one thread can access this db at a time.
        if (instance == null){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), whatEverUserDB.class, "whatever_user_database")
                    //.enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()
                    //.allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() //if we don't do this and try to increase the version, the app will crash, this avoids this by deleting the tables and starting from scratch
                    //.addCallback(roomCallback)
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    */



 /*   private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
          //  new PopulateDBAsyncTask(instance).execute();
        }
    };


 private  static class PopulateDBAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { // Creating this async task to populate the db for test users
        private WhatEverUserDAO whatEverUserDAO;

        private PopulateDBAsyncTask(whatEverUserDB db){
            whatEverUserDAO = db.whatEverUserDAO();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            whatEverUserDAO.insertUser(new WhatEverUser("admin","admin@admin.com","password"));
            whatEverUserDAO.insertUser(new WhatEverUser("test1","admin1@admin.com","password"));
            whatEverUserDAO.insertUser(new WhatEverUser("test2","admin2@admin.com","password"));


            return null;
        }
    }

*/






// must extend roomDb and be abstract
// version must be changed every time we create a new db from scratch
// we should not leave userDB on devices, this will eventually need to be grabbed from our own sql server so this class may be removed later TODO
```

Repo

```
package com.example.whatever.repositories;

import android.app.Application;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.whatever.db.WhatEverUser;
import com.example.whatever.db.WhatEverUserDB;
import com.example.whatever.interfaces.WhatEverUserDAO;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;

// UserRepo connects the view model to the room. Transmits LiveData from room to ViewModel
// takes requests from ViewModel
// This class is not necessary but recommended , it provides an abstraction between the db and vm
// Repo can grab data from the SQLite db or an internet resource
// REPO can make API calls
// The viewModel calls methods from the repo directly
// The repo calls methods from the DAO

public class WhatEverUserRepo {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private WhatEverUserDAO whatEverUserDao;
    private LiveData userName;
    private LiveData userPassword;

    public WhatEverUserRepo(Application application){


        WhatEverUserDB database = WhatEverUserDB.getDatabase(application);
        whatEverUserDao = database.whatEverUserDAO();
        //userName = whatEverUserDao.getUsername();




    }
    public void setUserName(LiveData whatEverUserName){


            userName = whatEverUserName;
    }



    public void getUserName(WhatEverUser whatEverUser){



    }

    public void insertUserName(String userName){



    }
    public void getUserEmail(String whatEverUserEmail){



    }

    public void insertUserEmail(String whatEverUserEmail){



    }





    public void insertUserPassword(String userPassword){


    }



   /* public LiveData<String> getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }*/
// we will need to copy this method and use it in each public method above for each action
 private static class getUserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<WhatEverUser,Void, Void> {

        private WhatEverUserDAO wUserDAO ;
        private WhatEverUser whatEverUser;

    private getUserAsyncTask(WhatEverUser whatEverUser){
            this.wUserDAO = wUserDAO;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(WhatEverUser... whatEverUser) {
            //wUserDAO.getUsername();
            return null;
        }
    }


public void startThread(View view){
    for (int i = 0; i  < 10; i++){
        Log.d(TAG,"startThread: " + i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public void stopThread(View view){



}



}
```

ViewModel

```
package com.example.whatever.viewModels;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;

import com.example.whatever.db.WhatEverUser;
import com.example.whatever.repositories.WhatEverUserRepo;

public class ViewModelEmailLogin extends AndroidViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "WhatEverLogState";

    private WhatEverUserRepo whatEverUserRepo;
    private MutableLiveData<WhatEverUser> whatEverUser;
    private MutableLiveData<CharSequence> UserName = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<CharSequence> uPassword = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<CharSequence> UserEmail = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<WhatEverUser> WhatEverUser = new MutableLiveData<>();



     public ViewModelEmailLogin(@NonNull Application application) {

        super(application);
         Log.i(TAG, "Instanced");

         whatEverUserRepo = new WhatEverUserRepo(application);
         Log.i(TAG, "Set whatEverUserRepo");


         LiveData<WhatEverUser> whatEverUserLiveData; // not sure what this is for
         LiveData<CharSequence>UserEmail;
         LiveData<CharSequence>UserPassword;


    }





}
```

and Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.whatever"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = '2.2.0'
    def room_version = '2.2.5'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0"

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'


    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'


    //lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"

    // Room Components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"


 //   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //kapt "androidx.arch.persistence.room:compiler$room_version"
//    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"



}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: try keeping a different name for the database instead of 'whatever_user_table' as its also matching to table name.

Comment: The [Room docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) indicate you need a build dependency on  `annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version`.  Also, if you are not using Kotlin, remove the two ktx dependencies.

Comment: androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version
That fixed it ! Thanks! Could have sworn I had it already. Been stuck on this for 2 weeks. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the [Room setup instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room), the build dependencies must include:

`"annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"`